# how to get regexp_substr for a string

Tags: sql, oracle

In my table for the rows containing values like

```
sample>test Y10, 
Sample> y21
```

I want to get a substring like `y10`,`y21` from all rows. May I pls know how to get it. I tried with `regexp_substr,Instr` but not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that your string from column is devided by a `single space` .
It will give you last occurances which will be splited by `' '` a space

```
substr(your_string, 1, instr(yourString,' ') - 1)
```

OR you can achive this using `regexp_substr`

```
regexp_substr(your_String, '[^[:space:]]+', 1, -1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `yxx` is always preceded by a space, it should be as easy as doing this:

```
TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(mycolumn, ' y\d+', 1, 1, 'i'))
```

The above regular expression will grab `y` (note that it is case-insensitive, so it will grab `Y` as well) followed by an indefinite number (one or more) of digits. If you want to grab just two digits, replace `\d+` with `\d{2}`.

Also, please note that it will get the first occurrence only. Getting multiple occurrences is a bit more complicated, but it can still be done.